# Getting rid of latches in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I am building a simple debouncer with decrementing counter. The syntitizer is yelling that there are latches. I don't need latches. I just need flipflops. WHich part in the following code is creating latches?

Design: The block receives a value and if the value is different from the stored one, it starts to count down. As soon as the counter reaches 0, the block outputs the new value.

```
library IEEE;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

entity Debouncer is
    Generic (
          DB_DATA_WIDTH             :   integer range 1 to 8   := 8;
          DB_CLOCKS                 :   integer range 0 to 1023   := 3
    );
    Port(
        clk : in STD_LOGIC; --clock
        Sig : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (DB_DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);   --raw input signal
        Deb_Sig : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (DB_DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        Deb_Rdy : out STD_LOGIC;
        rst : in STD_LOGIC
    );--debounced output signal
end Debouncer;

architecture Behavioral of Debouncer is

    signal value_reg :STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (DB_DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    signal tick_counter : unsigned (9 downto 0);



begin

    process (clk, rst) is
    begin

        if (rst = '1') then

            --TO_UNSIGNED(DB_CLOCKS, tick_counter'length)
            tick_counter <= TO_UNSIGNED(DB_CLOCKS, tick_counter'length);
            value_reg <= (others=>'0');

        elsif (clk'event and clk= '1') then

            if (value_reg = Sig) then

                if (tick_counter /= 0) then
                    tick_counter <= tick_counter -1;
                end if;

            else

                value_reg <= Sig;
                tick_counter <= TO_UNSIGNED(DB_CLOCKS, tick_counter'length);

            end if;
        end if;

    end process;

    Deb_Rdy <= '1' when ( tick_counter = 0 ) else '0';--debouncing logic is assigned to the output Deb_sig
    Deb_Sig <= value_reg;

end Behavioral;
```

Log:

```
WARNING:Xst:1710 - FF/Latch <Inst_Debouncer/tick_counter_9> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <led_switches>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <Inst_Debouncer/tick_counter_8> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <led_switches>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <Inst_Debouncer/tick_counter_6> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <led_switches>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <Inst_Debouncer/tick_counter_5> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <led_switches>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <Inst_Debouncer/tick_counter_7> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <led_switches>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <Inst_Debouncer/tick_counter_3> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <led_switches>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <Inst_Debouncer/tick_counter_2> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <led_switches>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <Inst_Debouncer/tick_counter_4> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <led_switches>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
```

Comment: There are no latches; that's not what the error messages are telling you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your synthesizer is telling you that you only need a 2 bit tick_counter since you made DB_CLOCKS 3 in this case.  It isn't creating latches, it is trimming FF/Latches (in this case FF).